# Сортировка матрицы по сумме строк

Tags: php

*Характеристикой строки целочисленной матрицы назовем сумму ее положительных четных элементов. Переставляя строки заданной матрицы, расположить их в соответствии с ростом характеристик.*

```
function SortMatrixBySumOfRows($matrix) {
    // Этап 1. Ищу базовую сумму - сумма элементов первой строки
    $sum = 0;
    for($j = 0; $j < count($matrix[0]); $j++)
        $sum += $matrix[0][$j];

    // Этап 2. Сортировка по сумме строк
    $temp = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($matrix); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($matrix[$i]); $j++)
        {
            if($matrix[$i][$j] >= 0 
                && $matrix[$i][$j] % 2 == 0)
                $temp += $matrix[$i][$j];
        }
        if($temp > $sum) {
            for ($k = 0; $k < n; $k++){
                $buf = $matrix[$j][$k];
                $matrix[$j][$k] = $matrix[$j+1][$k];
                $matrix[$j+1][$k] = $buf;
                }
            $sum = $temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Народ, помогите разобраться с этапом 2.
Казалось, уже имея сумму можно уже делать легкую сортировку, но нужно написать еще один цикл, которые меняет элементы. Где облажался?**

Answer (score 0):

```
function har($a){ // Характеристика
    $h = 0;
    foreach($a as $k => $v){
        if($v > 0){ // Положительный
            if($v % 2 == 0){ // Чётный
                $h += $v
            }
        }
    }
    return $h;
}

// Сортировка
usort($matrix, function($a, $b){return har($a) > har($b)});
```

Comment: не работает как надо

Comment: Есть 1)пример матрицы,2) ожидаемый и 3)полученный результат?